# photo puzzle application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I want to build a photo puzzle application. Is there any sample code so I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the tutorial...

http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/2010/09/23/cocos2d-game-tutorial-building-a-slide-image-game/

part 2

http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/2011/03/17/cocos2d-game-tutorial-%E2%80%93-building-a-slide-image-game-part-2-with-solution/

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

And a sample code [QuartzDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score -1):

http://javascript.internet.com/games/picture-puzzle.html

Google is your friend.